# extract 2 numbers in the string long separated with a word

Tags: python, regex

Need construct regular expression

I have a lot of strings like the following strings...

> dog ‘alphabet: number 1234 time 321123 trigger bank_ 222-008. sentence
>
> cat ‘rando beta: nomber r 6503 timer 723126 sent city ml _ 231-014. letter
>
> av df ‚am: namber 1123 ]umer '145412 done town uk a suee

They all have randim words and randim numbers. but I need to extract 2 numbers (4 symbols and 6 symbols) separated with a word.
"1234" and "321123" in the first case "6503" and "723126" in the second case "1123" and "145412" in the third case.

I tried this one [0-9]+ [a-zA-Z]+ [0-9]+  and then delete the words between numbers , but this expression does not work for 3rd one. And I'd like to get only numbers without any words/symbols between.

Comment: Try `r"([0-9]+) \S+ '?([0-9]+)"`, see https://regex101.com/r/aVzvcF/1

Answer (score 1):

I'd use:

```
r"(?<!\d)(\d{4})\D+(\d{6})(?!\d)"
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/gbZto0/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

str = "dog ‘alphabet: number 1234 time 321123 trigger bank_ 222-008. sentence"

m = re.search('.*(\d{4}).*(\d{6})', str)
if m:
    print(m.group(1))
    print(m.group(2))
```

Output :

```
1234
321123
```

Regex explanation can be found [here](https://regex101.com/r/TGULag/1).

Comment: [You will have some problem if the string contains more digits](https://regex101.com/r/TGULag/3)